# Can you detect an lvalue destructuring from the right hand side of an assignment statement in Python?

Tags: python, destructuring

This is probably a bad idea, but I was curious if it was possible to achieve the following interface in python:

```
a = fn() # a = 5
a, b = fn() # a = 5, b = 6
```

versus what Python typically would do:

```
a = fn() # a = (5, 6)
a, b = fn() # a = 5, b = 6
```

In other words, can `fn` detect the destructuring type of the lvalue and return the appropriate object for it? In my case, I have a better version of a library that has a commodity counterpart with a slightly different interface. It would be nice if I could make that interface optional and therefore backwards compatible.

I kind of doubt this is possible or wise, but I am pretty curious about it.

Comment: Afaik, no, this isn't possible. And I know this isn't what you're asking, but for the second, you could do `a, *_ = fn()` to ignore all the other returned elements.

Comment: So you want to have function overloading (which does not exist in Python), based not on the argument list but on the return "amount", i.e. the amount of names the result should bind to on the lhs of an assignment. I do not think any language will do that, but maybe structured bindings in the newer C++ standards can do this?